# Any difference between 'authenticate_user!', 'user_signed_in?', & 'if current_user'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This may be a dumb question, but I'm finishing up this app using Devise & am just wondering, is there any significant difference between `authenticate_user!`, `user_signed_in?`, & `if current_user`? If so, then in what cases would I not use one or the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'significant difference', all these do different things:

```
authenticate_user!  # Signs user in or redirect
user_signed_in?     # Checks whether there is a user signed in or not
current_user        # Current signed in user
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb

Comment: facepalm.. a bit sleep deprived & i should've looked at the sources first. thank you..

Comment: Quick question (may be another dumb one), I'm using `before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]`.. There's no problem with using this over `user_signed_in?`, right?

Comment: Depends on what you want it to do - `authenticate_user!` will redirect an invalid user, but only on the `index` route. `user_signed_in?` returns a boolean, so you can use that for greater control if you need it...

Answer (score 2):

Just reading the variable names you can see they are not the same thing.

```
authenticate_user!
```

This is a method to check user authentication, i.e., check if login and password matches.

```
user_signed_in?
```

This method checks if a user is signed in on the application. If there are any data inside the session that tells the application a user is signed in.

```
current_user
```

This gets the user that is logged in the application.